# SQL : Server dynamic PIVOT query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to make the below Pivot SQL query dynamic.

List of the dynamic customer should be retrieved from below query.

**Customer List Query**

```
SELECT
  Cust_Name
FROM dbo.Customer
INNER JOIN dbo.Service
  ON dbo.Customer.Cust_ID = dbo.Service.Cust_ID
WHERE [Next_Service] BETWEEN '2017-09-01' AND '2015-09-10'
```

**Pivot query**

```
Select *
from
(
  select Customer.Cust_Name,Agreementlist.ProductQty,Store.Product_Name as Refill
  from dbo.Agreement INNER JOIN  dbo.Agreementlist ON dbo.Agreement.Agreement_ID = dbo.Agreementlist.Agreement_ID  INNER JOIN  dbo.Customer
  ON dbo.Customer.Cust_ID = dbo.Agreement.Cust_ID INNER JOIN  Store on Store.Pro_ID = dbo.Agreementlist.ProID  where  CatID='2' and Agreement.Status='Approved'

) x
pivot
(
  sum(ProductQty)
  for Cust_Name in ("list of customers resulted from the first query")  
) p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a cursor to loop over your customers and add them to a variable. This here works.

```
  declare @gruppe nvarchar(max)
  declare @gruppeSql nvarchar(max)
  declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

  DECLARE myCustomers CURSOR FOR

  SELECT Cust_Name FROM dbo.Customer INNER JOIN dbo.Service
  ON dbo.Customer.Cust_ID = dbo.Service.Cust_ID
  WHERE [Next_Service] BETWEEN '2017-09-01' AND '2015-09-10' 

  set @gruppeSql = ''

  OPEN myCustomers
  FETCH NEXT FROM myCustomers INTO @gruppe
  IF (@@FETCH_STATUS>=0)
  BEGIN
  SET @gruppeSql = @gruppeSql +'[' +@gruppe+']'
  FETCH NEXT FROM myCustomers INTO @gruppe
  END
  WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-1)
  BEGIN
  IF (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-2)
  SET @gruppeSql = @gruppeSql  + ',[' +@gruppe+']'
  FETCH NEXT FROM myCustomers INTO @gruppe
  END
  CLOSE myCustomers
  DEALLOCATE myCustomers 

  SET @gruppeSql = replace(@gruppesql,'''','')

  --select @gruppeSql
  SET @SQL = '
  Select *
  from
  (
   select Customer.Cust_Name,Agreementlist.ProductQty,Store.Product_Name as 
   Refill
   from dbo.Agreement INNER JOIN  dbo.Agreementlist ON 
   dbo.Agreement.Agreement_ID = dbo.Agreementlist.Agreement_ID  INNER JOIN  
   dbo.Customer
   ON dbo.Customer.Cust_ID = dbo.Agreement.Cust_ID INNER JOIN  Store on 
   Store.Pro_ID = dbo.Agreementlist.ProID  where  CatID=''2'' and 
   Agreement.Status=''Approved''

  ) x
  pivot
  (
     sum(ProductQty)
     for Cust_Name in ('+@gruppesql+')  
  ) p'

  print @sql
  exec(@sql)
```

**SQL Print**
[image]

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Error : Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Invalid column name 'Gruppe'.

Comment: Sorry remove gruppe - it was from my old SQL - I just edited the rows.

Comment: Just edited my SQL so i set brackets if you have spaces in your customer name. And then i removed the gruppe from the SQL to the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this SQL script to create dynamic Pivot

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[dynamicPivot]
(@tablename        VARCHAR(250),
 @pivotColumn      VARCHAR(250),
 @groupBy          VARCHAR(8000),
 @aggregateColumns VARCHAR(250),
 @aggregation      VARCHAR(250),
 @execute          INT           = 0
)
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000), @pivotcols VARCHAR(8000)= '';
         DECLARE @result TABLE(result VARCHAR(8000));
         SET @sql = '
declare
    @pivotcols varchar(8000) = '''';
with cte as (
select distinct '+@pivotColumn+', ''[''+cast('+@pivotColumn+' as varchar(250))+'']'' col
from '+@tablename+')
select @pivotcols = @pivotcols + col + '',''
from cte
order by '+@pivotColumn+';
set @pivotcols = left(@pivotcols, len(@pivotcols)-1);
select @pivotcols result';
         INSERT INTO @result
         EXEC (@sql);
         SELECT @pivotcols = result
         FROM @result;
         SET @sql = '
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
       '+@groupBy+CASE @groupBy
                      WHEN ''
                      THEN ''
                      ELSE ', '
                  END+@pivotColumn+', '+@aggregateColumns+' 
    FROM '+@tablename+'
) AS s
PIVOT
(
    '+@aggregation+'
    FOR '+@pivotColumn+' IN ('+@pivotcols+')
)AS p;';
         IF @execute = 0
             PRINT(@sql);
             ELSE
         EXEC (@sql);
     END;
GO
```